# Precedence of cell group tokens over package's expressions

Tags: bugs, front-end, packages, system, parsing

**Bug introduced in V10.4 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

> [CASE:4072996]

---

```
SystemOpen @ Export[
  FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.m" }]
, "x = \"
    (* ::Chapter:: *)
    (* Metadata*)
  \""
, "Text"
]
```

[image]

Well, I didn't expect this. It wasn't how I faced it, I just had a string template for a package inside a package and when I reopened the file it was corrupted.

Is this expected? Shouldn't expressions have priority over package tokens. The more that it is hard to find any documentation about `(* ::Section:: *)` and friends.

What practices should I follow to not be hit by this again?

Comment: Wow now that is a nasty bug. WRI's package parse is already pretty slow. Good to know it's somewhat unreliable too!

Comment: @b3m2a1 I just noticed it is even worse, I assumed it only happens when the line starts with the token, but even `whatever code "(* ::Chapter:: *)"` will break it :P

Comment: Would it be acceptable to escape the special tag as `\(*` or `(\*`? I think they must get prior treatment before standard parsing.

Comment: @Silvia I will try later but it depends how much hassle it would be to use it and what implications it would have, e.g. I want to `Export["test.m", x, "Text"]` and it should open as a valid package with chapter correctly parsed as a real token.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this, bearing in mind that Mathematica is really a [bootstrapping](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieronymus_Carl_Friedrich_von_M%C3%BCnchhausen#/media/File:M%C3%BCnchhausen-Sumpf-Hosemann.png) system, i.e., it can fix itself (except `Dynamic`, that seems pretty unfixable)

```
file = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.m"}];
Export[file,
  "x = \"
      (* ::Chapter:: *)
      (* Metadata*)
    \"", "Text"];
bin = Import[file, "Text"];
Export[file, "", "Text"];
NotebookWrite[nb = NotebookOpen[file], ExportString[bin, "Text"]];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[nb, "Save"]]
```

[image]

Comment: 1) next time you open the file the issue persists so it would have to be a default action to open .m files 2) which can't be enforced if you just double click on a .m file from e.g. desktop.